# GPS location spoofing, excluding selected apps

Tags: android, gps, privacy

I am looking for an app to spoof my phone's location, but will allow me to specify which apps I want to exclude from using a fake location (Google Maps, Waze, etc.)

I have looked at [Fake GPS Location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en) and [Fake GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.newapphorizons.fakegps&hl=en) but they will spoof a location that affects all apps.

Comment: Don't use any of those myself, but I have a list of [location spoofers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_sharefake#group_566) you could check with while waiting for good answers. And if your device is rooted: several [permission managers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions), e.g. *Xprivacy*, can do that on per-app basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are rooted, [XPrivacy](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy#frequently-asked-questions) will accomplish the goal you desire.  It is an Xposed module, so you will need to install the [Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-faq-issues-t2735540) first.

In XPrivacy, you can select which apps have access to Location Providers (including GPS), and which are fed information of your choosing.

Be aware that some apps will request a list of all nearby WiFi access points, including how strong the signal strength is to each access point.  When corrolated with previously collected data, that can be used to pinpoint your position within less than a meter.  You will need to use XPrivacy to block access to that data as well.

Note also that some apps will request the [Mobile Country Code (MCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code) for your device.  You can use XPrivacy to block or change this as well.

Comment: +1 for those additional details to be aware of (WiFi, MCC/MNC)! With *XPrivacy* and its granularity, it should be no issue blocking that while keeping the remains open (i.e. allowing WiFi network access while forbidding to read details on connected networks).